# Error on Submit File to Django API from Angular

Tags: django, angular, api

I am using Django as my API and trying to upload Pdf file from Angular
I have used the HttpModule to post the file with the name, company, year and document

I have tested the post url on Postman and it works
[link to the postman API showing the post request was successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBHWg.png)

> When I click the upload there is no activity on the Network tab and no output on console

This is my Django API

**url.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'reports', views.ReportViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^upload/$', TestUploadView.as_view(), name='upload'),
    #path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from .models import Report

class ReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('name', 'company', 'year', 'document')
```

**Angular code in app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-frontend'
  name!: string;
  company!: string;
  year!: string;
  document!: File;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  onNameChanged(event: any) {
    this.name = event.target.value;
  }
  onCompanyChanged(event: any) {
    this.company = event.target.value
  }
  onYearChanged(event: any) {
    this.year = event.target.value
  }
  onDocumentChanged(event: any) {
    this.document = event.target.files[0];
  }

  Upload() {
    const uploadData: FormData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('name', this.name);
    uploadData.append('company', this.company);
    uploadData.append('year', this.year);
    uploadData.append('document', this.document);
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reports/', uploadData).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" (change)="onNameChanged($event)" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Company:
    <input type="text" (change)="onCompanyChanged($event)" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Year:
    <input type="text" (change)="onYearChanged($event)" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Document:
    <input type="file" (change)="onDocumentChanged($event)" />
</label>
<br />

<button type="submit" ng-click="Upload()">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Try change from ng-click to (click) <button type="submit" (click)="Upload()">Upload</button>

I believe that ng-click comes from AngularJS and not Angular

Comment: I used (click) but have the same thing, no activity on the network tab 
not sure if the click is calling the Upload() method for the POST